# Error When writing Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm testing the following hql but getting an error

```
String SQL="From Bid bid where bid.Auction.AuctionId=3655"
```

Class Bid Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jan 19, 2011 5:25:35 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Bid" table="BID">
        <id name="BidId" type="long">
            <column name="BIDID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="BidAmount" type="long">
            <column name="BIDAMOUNT" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="User" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Users" fetch="join">
            <column name="UserId" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="auction" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Auction" fetch="join" lazy="false">
            <column name="AuctionId" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="TimePosted" type="java.util.Date" access="field">
            <column name="TIMEPOSTED" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Auction Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 28, 2010 9:14:12 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Auction" table="AUCTION">
        <id name="AuctionId" type="long">
            <column name="AUCTIONID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="StartTime" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="STARTTIME" />
        </property>
        <property name="EndTime" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="ENDTIME" />
        </property>
         <property name="DatePlaced" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="DatePlaced" />
        </property>
        <property name="StartingBid" type="long">
            <column name="STARTINGBID" />
        </property>
        <property name="MinIncrement" type="long">
            <column name="MININCREMENT" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="CurrentItem" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Item" fetch="join" not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" lazy="false">
            <column name="CURRENTITEM" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="AuctionStatus" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="AUCTIONSTATUS" />
        </property>
        <property name="BestBid" type="long">
            <column name="BESTBID" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="User" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Users" fetch="join">
            <column name="UserId" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Auction of: com.BiddingSystem.Models.Bid [From com.BiddingSystem.Models.Bid bid where bid.Auction.AuctionId=3655 and bid.User.UserId=3657]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1449)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveFirstChild(DotNode.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4774)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3944)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1972)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at com.BiddingSystem.server.ServiceImpl.getBid(ServiceImpl.java:1463)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:174)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this will work

```
String SQL="From Bid bid where bid.auction.auctionId=3655"
```

Properties are supposed to always start with lowercase characters in java.

Comment: Thanks you placed on the track the working sql was String SQL="From Bid bid where bid.auction.AuctionId=3655"

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this Select distinct bid.auction from Bid bid

Comment: Yes: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Answer (score 2):

Based on your `Bid` mapping file, your SQL should be like this:-

```
String SQL="From Bid bid where bid.auction.AuctionId=3655"
```

But seriously, your camel-casing in your beans are really messed up. Property names in your bean **SHOULD** begin with small letter first (ex: `auctionId`, `auction`, `timePosted`, etc).

Comment: s it possible to do something like this Select distinct bid.auction from Bid bid

Comment: yes, that should work. See 14.7 at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation for more information.